# Python update table's value using another table's values

Tags: python, pandas

I use python and pandas.

I want to make like a [df_result].
df1's and df2's a,b is condition.
if a,b is equal value, change the df1's 'd' column value by df2's 'd' column value.

how to make it?
I don't know any solution..

**df1**

```
a b c d

1 2 5 1

1 5 5 1

2 3 4 1
```

**df2**

```
a b d

1 2 2

1 2 2

2 3 4
```

**df_result**

```
a b c d

1 2 5 2

1 5 5 1

2 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if same length and same index values in both DataFrames with comparing both columns with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1['d'] = np.where((df1[['a', 'b']] == df2[['a', 'b']]).all(axis=1), df2['d'], df1['d'])
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  5  2
1  1  5  5  1
2  2  3  4  4

print (df1[['a', 'b']] == df2[['a', 'b']])
      a      b
0  True   True
1  True  False
2  True   True

print ((df1[['a', 'b']] == df2[['a', 'b']]).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Another more general solution for matching by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, but is necessary unique rows in `df2` by columns `a` and `b` by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), last [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) and remove unnecessary column `d_`:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(['a','b']), on=['a','b'], how='left', suffixes=('_',''))
         .assign(d= lambda x: x['d'].combine_first(x['d_']))
         .drop('d_', axis=1))

print (df)
   a  b  c    d
0  1  2  5  2.0
1  1  5  5  1.0
2  2  3  4  4.0

print (df2.drop_duplicates(['a','b']))
   a  b  d
0  1  2  2
2  2  3  4

print (df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(['a','b']), on=['a','b'], how='left', suffixes=('_','')))
   a  b  c  d_    d
0  1  2  5   1  2.0
1  1  5  5   1  NaN
2  2  3  4   1  4.0
```